# Use same component at two place and identify whether in Account page or not with APP Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning record page component and i want to use this component in Opportunity and Account page.
How to i identify whether we are in **Account** page or **Opportunity** Page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try this if you are using App builder for both pages with same
>   component

In your **component** open -> **DESIGN** tab in left sidebar **Bundle Version Settings**

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="isHomePage" label="Home Page" description="Home page or not" />
</design:component>
```

> Access it as Boolean value in main component

Eg.

```
<aura:attribute name="isHomePage" type="Boolean" />
```

> In App builder there you can check or unchecked according to your page
>   type
>
> Based on Boolean value you can hide/show your data using
>   **Aura:if**

**You can use above method even in non sObject page**

**Or simple you can use** *vignesh* **answer**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasSObjectName">
  {!v.sObjectName}
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I am going to use your ans as i need a boolean value to check we are at what page.. Thnks buddy

Answer (score 4):

Implement `force:hasSObjectName`  interface if your component needs to know the API name of the object of the currently displaying record.

This interface adds an attribute named sObjectName to your component.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasSObjectName">
  {!v.sObjectName}
</aura:component>
```

Comment: The interface automatically creates the attribute, so there's no need to write it in to your component.